# Cortisol in sharks

Tags: endocrinology, marine-biology, stress

Is there an established method for measuring stress hormone levels, like cortisal, in sharks? If so, is it known what levels of such hormones create significant detrimental effects like decreased immunity?

Comment: This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site — have you tried searching for "stress hormone levels sharks"? Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17977765/